# Perform operation for a collection of instances involving a specific class member

Tags: c++, class, iteration

Imagine a class Person like this:

```
class Person {
        public:
        double height;
        double weight;
};
```

I have a vector containing instances of this class:

```
std::vector<Person> crowd;
```

Now I want to calculate the mean height and weight, so I do:

```
double mean_height = 0, mean_weight = 0;
for (int i=0; i<crowd.size(); i++) {
        mean_height += crowd[i].height;
        mean_weight += crowd[i].weight;
}
mean_height /= crowd.size();
mean_weight /= crowd.size();
```

Since I use the mean operation a lot in my code, I would like to be able to write a function that does something like:

```
mean_height = crowd_mean(crowd, height);
```

where the argument 'height' (whatever type it is) specifies that I want to perform the mean of all 'height' members over all the instances in the vector. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: better to use range-based-`for` or iterators, than indexing, if you don't ever need the index. as for the more general question, I suggest searching about pointers to member variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [pointer to a class member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) to do this.  That would look like

```
double crowd_mean(const std::vector<Person>& crowd, double Person::*member)
{
    double mean = 0;
    for (const auto& elem : crowd)
        mean += elem.*member;
    return mean / crowd.size();
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<Person> foo(10);
    auto result = crowd_mean(foo, &Person::weight);
}
```

---

If you want to make this more generic then you can make the function a function template like

```
template <typename T>
double crowd_mean(const std::vector<T>& crowd, double T::*member)
{
    double mean = 0;
    for (const auto& elem : crowd)
        mean += elem.*member;
    return mean / crowd.size();
}
```

Comment: BTW you're passing your persons by value

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Fixed and sorry

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 At least we show how to use the different for loop versions ;)

Comment: Works great! And your solution also taught me how to iterate without using indexes. Double cheers ^^

Answer (score 3):

> Is there an easy way to do this?

Yes!

**You want a [pointer-to-member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members).**

You pass it like `&Person::height`, take it like `double Person::*member`, and use it like `obj.*member`.

Example:

```
#include <vector>

class Person {
    public:
        double height;
        double weight;
};

double crowd_mean(const std::vector<Person>& crowd, double Person::*member)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (std::size_t i=0; i<crowd.size(); i++) {
            result += crowd[i].*member;
    }

    result /= crowd.size();

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Person> crowd;

    const double mean_height = crowd_mean(crowd, &Person::height);
    const double mean_weight = crowd_mean(crowd, &Person::weight);
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01488e34bc9acbd1))

Comment: `return std::accumulate(std::begin(crowd), std::end(crowd), 0.0, [&](double d, const Person& p) { return d + p.*member; }) / crowd.size();` ;- 0

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeeeeeeah no :P